# How do I find out what's different between two different Ubuntu kernels?

Tags: kernel, configuration

I have inherited a machine that will boot under 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linus 5.13.0-27generic x86_64) but not under ...0-28... or later versions.

Someone thinks an additional module may also have been added.

How do I find out what's different between the working and non-working kernels?

Is there something which lets me list what's in the kernels and associated files?
Are there copies of the old configuration files?

I have a fair amount of Unix knowledge, but little insight into the admin and config tools of Ubuntu

Thanks for any light you can shed

-Doug

Comment: You can diff the two config files. If that doesn't help I only know of bisecting the kernel to isolate the problematic commit. Bisection is time consuming, involving git, and kernel compiling (about 15 compiles).

Comment: Luckily, the old config files stay around in the upgrade process, so I was able to find the config files and diff them.  That leaves only a few things to swap in and out!  Thanks, your suggestion led me to the right place!